# Which Unicode character looks most similar to a (docker) container?

Tags: docker, unicode, containers

Which Unicode character looks most similar to a (docker) container? Google doesn't find anything.

Comment: A stack would also work, of course.

Comment: I think everyone would understand  intuitively...

Comment: "Google does not find anything... but it _did_ find your question! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using custom fonts like this one: https://fontawesome.com/icons/docker

Custom fonts could use not reserved location of unicode to host their own characters. As for existing unicode characters check out this website https://www.rapidtables.com/code/text/unicode-characters.html

Comment: I want a "standard character", not a custom font.

Comment: Maybe this one from the standard unicode https://emojipedia.org/spouting-whale/

Comment: Inspired by @Cosmos547 : maybe a "file box"? https://emojipedia.org/card-file-box/